# How to fetch the CloudWatch metrics data for EC2 instances

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to fetch the Cloudmetrics data for my EC2 instance so that I can draw graphs using those data and display it on my android device. How do I do that? Is there any sample program or tutorial for the same?

Thanks in advance.

This is what I am doing:

```
private static void findCloudWatchData()  {

    AmazonCloudWatchClient cloudWatch = new AmazonCloudWatchClient(new BasicAWSCredentials(AccessKey, SecretKey));
    cloudWatch.setEndpoint("monitoring.us-east-1.amazonaws.com");
    long offsetInMilliseconds = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    Dimension instanceDimension = new Dimension();
    instanceDimension.setName("instanceid");
    instanceDimension.setValue(instanceid);

    GetMetricStatisticsRequest request = new GetMetricStatisticsRequest()
            .withStartTime(new Date(new Date().getTime() - offsetInMilliseconds))
            .withNamespace("AWS/EC2")
            .withPeriod(60 * 60)
            .withMetricName("CPUUtilization")
            .withStatistics("Average")
            .withDimensions(Arrays.asList(instanceDimension))
            .withEndTime(new Date());

    GetMetricStatisticsResult getMetricStatisticsResult = cloudWatch.getMetricStatistics(request);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure it gets to the crux of your problem, but your code won't work correctly as written. Dimension names are case-sensitive, so you should set the name to "InstanceId" rather than "instanceid".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have tagged your question with *android* I assume that you want to fetch CloudWatch-Metrics for your EC2 Instances in an *Android-App*.
So this might be a good starting point for you:

- [Getting Started with the AWS SDK for Android](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/gsg/Welcome.html) .

You need to:

1. download [AWS SDK for Android](http://aws.amazon.com/de/sdkforandroid/)
2. create your access keys for AWS (via IAM)
3. read the documentation for [aws-android-sdk-VERSION-cloudwatch.jar](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/)
4. start using the fetched data from CloudWatch

Regards

Tom

Comment: Is there any sample program or tutorial for the same?

Comment: The AWS SDK for Android contains examples. They are probably not exactly suitable for your use-case but you can at least get the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you are struck only with reading the data and plotting the graph.

```
private static void findCloudWatchData()  {

LinkedHashMap<Date,Double> map=new HashMap<Date,Double>();
AmazonCloudWatchClient cloudWatch = new AmazonCloudWatchClient(new BasicAWSCredentials(AccessKey,     SecretKey));
cloudWatch.setEndpoint("monitoring.us-east-1.amazonaws.com");
long offsetInMilliseconds = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
Dimension instanceDimension = new Dimension();
instanceDimension.setName("instanceid");
instanceDimension.setValue(instanceid);

GetMetricStatisticsRequest request = new GetMetricStatisticsRequest()
        .withStartTime(new Date(new Date().getTime() - offsetInMilliseconds))
        .withNamespace("AWS/EC2")
        .withPeriod(60 * 60)
        .withMetricName("CPUUtilization")
        .withStatistics("Average")
        .withDimensions(Arrays.asList(instanceDimension))
        .withEndTime(new Date());

GetMetricStatisticsResult getMetricStatisticsResult = cloudWatch.getMetricStatistics(request);
}

//To read the Data
for (Datapoint dp : result.getDatapoints()) {
    map.put(dp.getTimeStamp(), dp.getAverage());   //or getMaximum() or whatever Statistics you are interested in. You can also maintain a list of the statistics you are interested in. Ex: request.setStatistics(list) 
}
```

Note that the datapoints are NOT in order. Sort the HashMap and plot the graph.

Comment: I have fetched the values from cloudwatch..now need to plot the graph..which java graph library to use?

Answer (score 0):

I found that `AWS/Billing` metrics "live" only in one region - *us-east-1*.

Also, AWS CLI (`aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics`) will errorr out if you try to grab more than 1440 data points from CloudWatch.
If you encounter it set larger `--period`.

Similar to what you are trying to achieve using Java on Android I wrote [EC2_Metrics_Plotter](https://github.com/alexbuz/EC2_Metrics_Plotter/blob/master/README.md) for OS Windows using Python/matplotlib.